# Response XML without NameSpaces

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, soapui

I'm using a endpoint SOAP created On Spring Framework using JAXB,  but I want that my anwers(Expected Response) return without prefix when I Send Request One, but this is returned like is showed on Current Response:.

How can I do to return a message SOAP without namespaces?

Request One

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <urn:ZProveerDatosPagoProveed2>
        <Bukrs>RG10</Bukrs>
        <Langu>S</Langu>
        <Lifnr>00000000</Lifnr>
    </urn:ZProveerDatosPagoProveed2>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Current Response:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap-env:Header/>
<soap-env:Body>
    <n0:ZProveerDatosPagoProveed2Response xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
        <Adrnr>0000</Adrnr>
        <Bankk>0000</Bankk>
        <Bankn>0000</Bankn>
        <Bkont>0000</Bkont>
        <Iban>ES0000</Iban>
        <KoinhFi>ROBLES AVN</KoinhFi>
        <Land1>TH</Land1>
        <Landx>XXXXX</Landx>
        <Name1>ROBLES AVN</Name1>
        <Pstlz>0000</Pstlz>
        <Stcd1>A0000</Stcd1>
        <Stras>ROBLES AVN</Stras>
        <Swift>XXXXX</Swift>
        <Text1_052>ROBLES AVN</Text1_052>
        <Zterm>Z000</Zterm>
    </n0:ZProveerDatosPagoProveed2Response>
</soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Expected Response:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap-env:Header/>
 <soap-env:Body>
     <ZProveerDatosPagoProveed2Response xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
         <Adrnr>0000</Adrnr>
         <Bankk>0000</Bankk>
         <Bankn>0000</Bankn>
         <Bkont>0000</Bkont>
         <Iban>ES0000</Iban>
         <KoinhFi>ROBLES AVN</KoinhFi>
         <Land1>TH</Land1>
         <Landx>XXXXX</Landx>
         <Name1>ROBLES AVN</Name1>
         <Pstlz>0000</Pstlz>
         <Stcd1>A0000</Stcd1>
         <Stras>ROBLES AVN</Stras>
         <Swift>XXXXX</Swift>
         <Text1_052>ROBLES AVN</Text1_052>
         <Zterm>Z000</Zterm>
     </ZProveerDatosPagoProveed2Response>
```

Comment: That "expected response" looks very odd to me. It's declaring a namespace alias for n0, but never actually using it. Your current response looks correct, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet The problem that I get is that the service(publisher - oracle) that is consuming my service do not recognize the prefixes.  
I was thinking if was posible return an answer SOAP without namespaces. I know that this could not be sense, 
but I do not find another way to comunicate with this client.

Comment: It shouldn't need to *recognize* the alias - that's what the URL is being specified for. Given that SOAP responses basically *always* use namespaces, I really think the problem might be a different one. This would be a SOAP client that couldn't talk to *anything*.